# How to assign value to a static variable in a non-static function?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Basically, `ajax` in aspx is polling the value return from .cs every 1000 ms from a `WebMethod` in .cs which is `static GetData()`. A property is declared as static `public static int Percent { get; set; }` . What i want to do is when a btn1 is clicked, it will assign the value into `Percent` and the `ajax` get the value from the `WebMethod static GetData()`.

### Downloader.aspx.cs

```
public static int PERCENT { get; set; }

[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
     return PERCENT ;
}

protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DownloadLibrary downloader = new DownloadLibrary();
     downloader.DoWorkSynchronous();
     bool isLibraryBusy = true;
     while (isLibraryBusy)
     {
        PERCENT  = library.returnValue();
        isLibraryBusy = downloader.IsBusy();
     }
}
```

### Downloader.aspx (ajax polling)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar();
              setTimeout(updateProgress, 100);
    });

   function updateProgress() {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Downloader.aspx/GetData",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: true,
                  success: function(msg) {
                      // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.

                      $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", msg.d);
                  }
              });
          }
```

I want to assign the value to `Percent` but unfortunately,i am unable to do it because the `Percent` is `static`. If i don't declare the `Percent` as `static`, the `GetData`() function unable to verify what `Percent` is. For `ajax` polling, `GetData()` have to be in `static`. How to assign value to a `static` variable in a `non-static function`?

Answer (score 3):

To reference a `static` member, you must prefix the member with the name of the class that defines it.

However, **don't do that!**

Your static variable will be common to every user of your web service. You may think it would be one copy per session, but that's not the case. There will be one copy for all users of the same web service.

Comment: wow..! this is dangerous.. if so, i have no idea on how to deal with the ajax polling... since i need to get the value return from .cs with ajax :\

Comment: If you want one data per user, you have to put it in session. There's a parameter you can pass to you `[WebMethod]` attribute to tell that you want to handle session in the web method. I'm not sure, but I think you just have to put `[WebMethod (true)]` as attribute.

Comment: @Johhny5 it's `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]`.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix your call to the static method with the class name.

```
Downloader.PERCENT = library.returnValue();
```

However as John points out, unless you can guarantee that you would only have one concurrent user for your application, then you shouldn't be using a static member for this task.

A better approach might be to store your PERCENT data in a session variable. That way it's only scoped per session, and not for the entire application.

```
Session["Percent"] = library.returnValue();
```

Then change your webmethod like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
     return (string)Session["Percent"];
}
```